# Array access through a list

Tags: arrays, fortran

My question is more of a quest for confirmation that the conclusions I have drawn are correct and to see if anyone has any smart "work-arounds".

My problems starts with a friend wanting to use `maxloc` to extract the location of the maximum value of an array and then use this result to read a corresponding element of an other array. I.e in pseudo code:

```
c = b(maxloc(a))
```

This however returns the error

```
Error: Rank mismatch in array reference at (1) (1/2)
```

(He is working with (N,N) arrays.)

I did some tests and I found that this does indeed not work.
My conclusion is that you need to do something like this:

```
program h
    integer :: a(2,2)
    integer :: id(2),id2(2)
    a(1,1) = 1; a(1,2) = 2;  a(2,1) = 3;  a(2,2) = 2
    id = maxloc(a)
    write(*,*) a(id(1),id(2))
end program h
```

It works and everyone is happy. Well, except me. I want to know if there is a better way of doing it. Is there something I am missing? An easy solution to the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is correct, `maxloc` returns an array (sort of a vector of indexes) and you cannot use it for  multidimensional array indexing. Vector indexing does something else and is mostly used for 1-D arrays.

You can use [`maxval()`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/MAXVAL.html) to get the maximum value of the array directly, but that may not be the thing you need in all cases.

You can also use associate and avoid declaring a new variable in the scope:

```
associate(id => maxloc(a))
  write(*,*) a(id(1),id(2))
end associate
```

but that will be more useful if your use is more complicated and cannot be just done by `maxval()`.

Comment: Wouldn't your method call `maxloc` twice?

Comment: Which method? Associate? No, it wouldn't.

Comment: Okay, I don't know enough about how `associate` works, and it'd be probably be optimised away anyway, but if not, wouldn't it call `maxloc` for each of the indices independently?

Comment: No, associates just stores the result of the expression into a temporary variable.